# Why are this variables undefined?(javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
var contacts = {
  name:["John", "Jane"],
  surname:["Smith", "Doe"]
}

var list=[];
var showContact=""; 

var manager = prompt("Welcome to your contacts manager!\nEnter a number \
                for:\n1: List contacts\n2: Add a contact\n0: Exit");

if (manager === "1") {
  for (i=0; i<contacts.name.length && i<contacts.surname.length; i++){
    showContact = console.log(contacts.name[i] + " " + contacts.surname[i]);
    list[i]= showContact;
  }
}

console.log(showContact);
console.log(list);
```

I am trying to understand this. I don't know why this variables are undefined. Maybe it is because of the scope? Anyway I don't understand it.

Shouldn't showContact have the value "John Smith" first and "Jane Doe" at the end of the loop, so printing it would return "Jane Doe"? And likewise with list, I get two values, which is correct, but they are undefined.

I would like not to make duplicate questions but in order to do that I would need to know what is wrong exactly in order to make a search on it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: *Which* variables exactly are you talking about, and why do you think they're undefined?

Answer (score 3):

because console.log does not return a value, try this instead :

```
showContact = contacts.name[i] + " " + contacts.surname[i];
list[i]= showContact;
```